# Right Side Space & Overflow-x hidden problem

Tags: overflow, space

I used overflow-x: hidden to get rid of the the right side space problem,it fixed but another problem is came with overflow-x hidden,that is my animated icon tag is hidden,button is hidden. How to use it to fix right side space problem without hidden the other elements?
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you add some examples of your code?

Comment: thanks for comment #wolmi . :) I solved this problem a few minutes ago.